# What are the merits of using CouchDB vs Hadoop to store/analyze web app log data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, couchdb, hadoop, analytics

I want to move up from using plain Rails log files for my web applications, so I can analyze page views and usage patterns. I've heard CouchDB is sometimes used for this.

On the other hand, I know of people who just feed the plain text log files into Hadoop and reduce them into summary stats that they then insert into MySQL.

What are the pros and cons of each of these two methods of logging and analyzing log files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only speak for CouchDB, but the main benefits of using a document database to store things like these are;

- They are schema less so that you can alter the schema of your log entries and still perform queries on the various editions of the schema you might have.
- The map/reduce algorithm is a very powerful way to do grouping queries.
- REST interface makes it technology agnostic in terms of consuming the data.
- Scaling is horizontal and "infinite".